# CSS как сверстать такой блок?

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой макет - девочка поверх блока с фоновой картинкой. Как сделать так, чтобы картинка девочки обрезалась внизу по контуру фона (где заштриховано)?

Answer (score 3):

Обычная прозрачная PNG а сзади градиент => demo

```css
.item {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  background: url(http://www.playcast.ru/uploads/2019/05/25/27084047.png), radial-gradient(circle at top, blue, blue 70%, transparent 70%, transparent 75%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Только фотографии в png тяжеловатые получаются...

Comment: Можно было бы, но фон задан картинкой, причём с другой стороны этого фона похожая ситуация, только изгиб фона другой. И нужно, чтобы наоборот - нижняя часть обрезалась (то есть, если смотреть по вашему демо, ноги девочки ниже колен должны быть скрыты)

Comment: @diman.suvor, а может svg?

Comment: @MaximLensky, он сказал часть девочки поверх какого-то фона, а дручая часть - под другим фоном. Три фона на одном div'е - можно. Но если средний слой сделать img'ем, то та часть, которая должна быть поверх, должна лежать в отдельном элементе, который будет лежать поверх img.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95928/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-maximlensky).

Answer (score 2):

Второй вариант ...геморойный

```html
<div style="width: 300px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 78 130" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <clipPath id="clipPath908">
   <path d="m122.52246 140.53571h77.7875l-1.20875 101.49591c-25.09648 12.74971-50.91753 20.42742-76.70637 28.33058z" fill="#333"/>
  </clipPath>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(-218.82693,-143.72368)">
  <g transform="translate(-16.036172,-74.835468)">
   <path d="m233.72117 218.55915h77.7875l0.0608 101.49591c-25.09648 12.74971-52.18706 20.42742-77.9759 28.33058z" fill="#f9c328"/>
   <path d="m262.45893 218.58511c6.45857 7.97287 22.94973 23.23169 49.06103 36.27005l-0.0117-36.29601z" fill="#d8782e"/>
   <path d="m233.69932 218.48459s31.81398 47.82903 77.77104 54.12657l0.0496-27.28106c-20.22605-5.30496-40.33923-13.75427-54.01373-26.9098z" fill="#dc524f"/>
  </g>
  <image transform="translate(96.432088,3.187972)" x="94.044159" y="140.53571" width="122.43582" height="170.69405" clip-path="url(#clipPath908)" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="http://www.skoro-svadba.com.ua/sites/default/files/foto_for_slider/img_0333_kopiya_1_0.png"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```